# Problem with tabular

Tags: tables, multicol, columns

It's my first time utilizing latex, and I can’t get rid of this problem.

im doing an article with two columns, using
`\begin{multicols}{2}` but the problem, is that when I put a table with `\begin{tabular}` the text inside its really big, so, the text cross the to the other column of the article and it superpose the text of the second column. I would really appreciate the help.
thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hiya, franco, welcome to our site! We'd certainly love to try and help you, but it'd be great if you could help us a little bit by providing what we call a *minimum working example*. There's a few ways to get one; one possible method is to *copy* your file, and then start stripping the copy down until you have the smallest possible one that demonstrates the problem. Once you have this file, if you could add it to your question, someone might be able to take it from there! Again, welcome!

Comment: search for wide table on the site you will find lots of answers, most likely your tabular has something like `{cccc}`  for 4 columns that do not allow lin ebreaking, you probably want `{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}` for 4 1cm wide columns (or whatever size you need)

Comment: Have you tried using a `table*` environment to encase the `tabular` material? A `table*` enviroment spans both text columns.

Comment: There is also \resizebox{.99\columnwidth}{...} from the graphicx and adjustbox packages.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way: use the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package, a component of the `sttools` bundle:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum, array, booktabs}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{strip}
  \centering

  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{p{0.25\textwidth}}}
    \toprule
    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      & Text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      & Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]